# Alternative proof Joule-Thomson process is isenthalpic

Tags: thermodynamics

I found in general as proof for the Joule Thomson experiment to be isenthalpic:
$$
 \Delta U = U_2 - U_1= \Delta W = - \int_{V_1}^{0} p_1  dV - \int_{0}^{V_2} p_2 dV = p_1 V_1 - p_2 V_2 
$$

and then

$$
U_2 - U_1 = p_1 V_1 - p_2 V_2 
$$
$$
U_2 +  p_2 V_2 = U_1  + p_1 V_1
$$
$$
H_1 = H_2
$$

But why can't I use the total derivative and say,

$$
dH = dU + pdV + Vdp = dQ - pdV + pdV + V dp 
$$

where the experiment is by constuction isobaric ($dp=0$) and adiabatic ($dQ=0$) and hence:

$$
d H = -pdV + pdV = 0 
$$

I'm sure this is wrong, otherwise someone would have used it in a book, why though?

Best!

Comment: It is isenthalpic because, there is no combustion or any reaction of system, only expansion. It is not isometric, not isobaric because system is closed, not isothermal because system is isolated and expansion of system causes decrease in pressure which is not compensated by heat. It is adiabatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We can always write $dU=\delta Q+\delta W$ and $dU=T\,dS-P\,dV$, but we can write $dU=\delta Q-P\,dV$ only for a reversible process. The [Joule–Thompson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect) isn't reversible, so in general $dU\neq \delta Q-P\,dV$. (Put another way, entropy increases—is generated—in a manner independent of heating, so $dS\neq\frac{\delta Q}{T}$; as you note, $\delta Q=0$.)
2. The pressure isn't constant in the Joule–Thompson process, so $dP=0$ doesn't hold.

This is why certain terms don't drop out as easily as they are proposed to do in the derivation above.

Comment: the pressure is constant in the separate volumes, here and there of the membrane, hence isobaric with respect to these, no?

Comment: "Isobaric" means the **system** pressure is constant through the process. You're taking the moving fluid as the system, correct? Its pressure is not constant.

Comment: I thought the proof from literature assumes in chamber one and chamber two, each separately, the pressure to be constant, hence the formula for the work being an integral over volume.

Comment: I’m not sure what that has to do with the fluid pressure changing.

Comment: First thing, $dU=\delta Q-pdV$ is valid for all processes. The doubtful is $dU=TdS-pdV$. But the difference between reversible and irreversible is any loss which can't be compensated. By doing external work, a system can be put in initial state, but there is loss in surrounding which we have no concern. So one can use the entropy form  of first law atleast in any closed system. It is used for isobaric, which is not closed even.

Comment: “*First thing, =− is valid for all processes. The doubtful is =−.*” The framework I used can be verified in any introductory thermodynamics textbook. This site is for discussing consensus physics; comments (or answers) with personal theories are inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The proper application of the first law of thermodynamics to steady Joule Thomson flow is $$\Delta h=Q-W_S$$where h is the enthalpy per unit mass of the flowing fluid, Q is the heat added per unit mass of flowing fluid, and $W_S$ is the shaft work done per unit mass of flowing fluid.  In Joule Thomson flow through a valve or porous plug, Q = 0 and $W_S=0$, so $\Delta h = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that the initial and final enthalpy is the same (i.e., $_{1}=_2$) does not necessarily mean the process is isenthalpic. An isenthalpic process is one in which the enthalpy is constant throughout the process. For that to be the case, the process needs to be reversible. The Joule-Thompson process is irreversible.

Hope this helps.